# Access control Exception

Tags: java, rmi

When I am running RMI Server in netbeans I am getting java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permissions within a policy file. An example can be found at the [RMI tutorial site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/running.html) and also further information concering [policy files](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html).